# How to create a project using mTurk API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

[image]

In mTurk website I can set a Project Name when creating hit. How can I create project by API using boto3 ? I have only `create_hit()` method which doesn't have `project_name` field ?

Can I create project using boto3 or this isn't available using API?

Comment: Please attach a code sample demonstrating what are you doing and how.